# Noncommutative ring, infinite and has no invertible elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there a noncommutative infinite ring with no invertible elements ?

Comment: The identity is always invertible. If your rings aren't required to have identity you can take the multiplication to be identically zero.

Comment: @qiaochu, that is a commutative ring ;-)

Comment: It does not a lot of sense to talk about invertible elements if there is no 1, I guess...

Comment: You can ask whether left multiplication by an element has an inverse which is given by left multiplication by some other element, but I take your point.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  yes that's what I am looking for,  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

The free algebra over the field with two elements on two generators has exactly one invertible element, the unit, and is not commutative.

Comment: Surely you need to work over $\mathbb{F}_2$ here?